# send URL via image view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, url, imageview

Is it possible to send an url via image by clicking the image, then opening the browser, for an app on the iPhone?

I'm using Xcode 4.4

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

1st A) add a gestureRecognizer to the UIView and use the following two lines of code...

1st B) or use instead a Button with BackGround Image and use the following two lines of code...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Any further questions?

Comment: Thanks!
I've still have just one more thing to ask.

If I use UIView, then there's an option that I can hide the image, if the image is hidden, the user can still click on it?
Because I want to put 4 images on the same space, then use a timer event to change their properties from hidden to show. I've done this in Delphi, but don't know if its possible to do on objective-c

Comment: You like to add 4 UIImageView's?
Add only one UIImageView and change the picture inside! So you only have 1 UIImageView, 1 GestureRecognizer, 1 GestureHandler...